# When reading from a txt file why doesn't python display all the lines?

Tags: python, file, readfile

While reading from a txt file with 8000 lines only the first 159 lines are shown and I was wondering why is this the case?

```
path = 'somepath/somefile.txt'

with open(path) as f:
    text = f.read()
print(text)
```

Expected outcome to be a display of all 8000 lines contained within the file when printing text.

Result was 159/8000 lines displayed when printing text.

Comment: What is the total size of your file? Without any argument, `f.read()` should read the full content of the file

Comment: Because you just used `read()`. If you want lines, use `readlines()` or iterate the file object.

Comment: how are you measuring the number of lines?

Comment: @Pierre V The total size of the file is only 714kb

Comment: @Chris Doyle I'm measuring the number of lines based off the actual number of lines in the txt file

Comment: @roganjosh I do actually want the entire file to be read at once but it stops and I'm trying to understand why it wont

Comment: Did you try `readlines` instead? That was part of my suggestion, which will eagerly load the lines of the file.

Comment: @roganjosh Yes I have tried readlines as well it still stops reading the lines at the 159th line.

Comment: Then it's not possible to answer with what you have given. Presumably the carriage return is not understood but you'll need a [mcve]

Comment: For example, it might not even be a simple text file at all, you just saved it with a `.txt` extension. We can't know this from what you gave

Comment: @roganjosh Alright, thank you I will try to be more descriptive with any future problems I ask about.

Comment: It's not just about future problems, you can [edit] this question.